# Does GTV or Android make use of HLS attributes RESOLUTION / CODECS?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, google-tv

We are streaming multi-bitrate HLS video to Android & Google TV devices. Currently our m3u8 variant playlist (ie the initial m3u8 that triggers playback) does not include the RESOLUTION and CODECS attributes. So a snippet from our file would be:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1459829
http://www.somedomain.com/somefolder/medium.m3u8
```

Whereas if we included the extra attributes, the same snippet would be:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1459829,RESOLUTION=530x424,CODECS="mp4a.40.5,avc1.4d401f"
http://www.somedomain.com/somefolder/medium.m3u8
```

My question is, do the video players in Android and Google TV make any use of these extra attributes? Is there any point in using them?

The reason I'm asking is that we often see a short pause when these players shift from one bitrate to another in the same playlist. Would these extra attributes have any effect on this behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [Apple's example stream](https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/resources/http-streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8) you'll see that they put some of that in:

> #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=232370,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,
>   avc1.4d4015"

These are useful hints to figure out what is the best choice for the device.